# Access RESTFul service wihtout have to login

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

We have an webapplication developed using Java, Spring 3.2.x and hibernate.

Implementing RestFul services by making the web app as server.(app is both webapp and server for rest).

Whenever I use http request to get data from server, do I need to login to the webapp? That is what my issue is right now. Untill I login I cannot get the details. Some how I need to bypass this login. Any suggestions! Thanks in advance! let me know if you need more details!

servlet part of web.xml

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

For security in webapp, using spring security.

following is my security.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:spring-authentication.xml"/>

    <security:http pattern="/" security="none"/>
    <security:http pattern="/login.*" security="none"/>
    <security:http pattern="/forgotpassword.*" security="none"/>
    <security:http pattern="/img/**" security="none"/>
    <security:http pattern="/css/**" security="none"/>
    <security:http pattern="/ws/**" security="none"/>

    <security:http realm="myrealm">

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/*jsp" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>

        <!-- order matters so these overrides must be above the star do below to work -->       
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/welcome.do" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/MyProfile.do" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>           
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/User.do" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/UserSearch.do" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/UserList.do" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/PasswordReset.do" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/*do"   access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/*csv" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/*pdf" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/ui/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <!-- Catch all to prevent public access to anything missed by proceeding filters -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />

        <security:form-login login-page="/login.do" 
            default-target-url="/welcome.do" 
            always-use-default-target="true"
            authentication-failure-url="/login.do?login_error=1" 
        />

        <security:logout logout-success-url="/login.do" />
        <security:http-basic/>
        <security:anonymous />
    </security:http>
    <bean id="authProvider" class="security.AuthenticationProvider">
    </bean>     
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">  
        <security:authentication-provider ref="authProvider"/>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

Comment: not clear, same url is used to display html content and for sending rest data ? this not clear "app is both webapp and server for rest"

Comment: @coder i have an webapp, in which we are implementing restful services. we are making that application as server so that diferent applications can call the rest data!

Comment: whats the url of rest service you using, is it present in <security:intercept-url> of your security config ?

Comment: @coder yes..<security:http pattern="/" security="none"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<security:http pattern="/" security="none"/>
```

will match only the root requests, so it will not match a request if it has any string after root context.
Your rest service url must be something like `http://host:port/context/<url>`

only `http://host:port/context` will match to pattern `"/"`

Solution:
Update the pattern in http tag to the rest service url with security="none".

I assume that you have some diff url in case you making a rest service call ?

Comment: changed to this, `<security:http pattern="/restURL/**" security="none"/>` but its not working for `http://host:port/context/restURL/id`..

Comment: when I do this, `http://host:port/context/restURL/id.do` it works. is it because of web.xml ` <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set "access" attribute to `permitAll` for the required rest url patterns in `<intercept-url>`. But you should enable SpEL in your http descriptor `<http use-expressions="true">`.